# Calling a function by a specific div's elements is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a accordion menu, where I have some links in some div with id. Here I have two div with id=collapseThree and id=collapseFour. Now I want a simple alert when any link element of collapseFour div is clicked. But no alert or console.log.

Here are my attempts. My view:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">
                        </span>Hospital</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk link-item"></span><a href="${createLink(controller: 'hospitalMember')}">Hospital Member</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">
                        </span>Somiti</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk link-item"></span><a href="${createLink(controller: 'jointMember')}">Somiti Member</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready");
        $("#collapseFour").on("click", ".link-item", function() {
            console.log("Clicked");
        });
    })
```

All I want to view the `Clicked` text.

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking the span? without css all i can do is assume the span isn't taking up any space and that you're actually clicking the anchor tag which has no associated event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `span` element with `link-item` class is not a parent of the clicked element, your code won't work properly. You can either move the closing tag of the `span` after the `a` element or use `.next()` function to refer to the next element just right after the `span`.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk link-item">
  <a href="${createLink(controller: 'jointMember')}">Somiti Member</a>
</span>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  $("#collapseFour .link-item").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">
                        </span>Hospital</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk link-item"></span><a href="${createLink(controller: 'hospitalMember')}">Hospital Member</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">
                        </span>Somiti</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk link-item"><a href="${createLink(controller: 'jointMember')}">Somiti Member</a></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. your suggestion works fine. But I need it with page redirect not in ajax. Can you please help?

Comment: I mean that `e.preventDefault()` stop to load the url. I want both. can you please help.

Comment: @SumonBappi You want to load the *url* or not? I've blocked it to be able to show you the result.

Comment: Yes, but I want the result after loading the page. sorry as if it is silly question to you

Comment: @SumonBappi *Result after loading the page*, you want it to work just right after the page is loaded? But, isn't it?

Comment: I find the solution. upload it as answer. anybody can be benefited.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the issue as follow :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".link-item").next().click(function(e) {
            var currId = $(this).closest(".collapse").attr("id");
            localStorage.setItem("currItem", currId);
        });

        $("#" + localStorage.getItem("currItem")).collapse('show')
    })
```